# Blender python: How to do something to objects that "have edges only, but no faces"?

Tags: python

Do someone knows why this condition is not working in blender python? Is there really no way to find objects, that have no faces/polygons, but edges?

```
if reference_mesh.edges and not reference_mesh.polygons: # Check if the reference mesh has only edges
# do something...
```

This line have to check, if an object has edges only and no faces. But it doesn't work. Always objects having faces are also included into this condition.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Addition:
If I use this

```
if reference_mesh.edges and len(reference_mesh.polygons) == 0: # Check if the reference mesh has only edges
    # do something...
```

Then it works for flat objects like a wireframe plane, but not for 3dimensional objects, like a wireframe cube.

Strange.

Comment: Hello ! Are you in object or edit mode ? Did you edit the mesh somehow before ? Make sure to update the mesh data beforehand

Comment: No I'm not in edit mode. I check the object, if it is wireframe only.

Comment: See my addition in my main post please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reasonable thing to do is to present the problem with the minimal example, e.g. the default cube, and show the code that works in a surprising way.

I can't reproduce your problem.

I removed all faces from the default cube:

```py
>>> C.object.data.polygons
bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].polygons

>>> bool(C.object.data.polygons)
False

>>> if C.object.data.polygons:
...     print("This won't print")
...     
>>> reference_mesh = C.object.data
>>> if reference_mesh.edges and not reference_mesh.polygons:
...     print("do something")
...     
do something

>>> # adding one face back to the cube
>>> if reference_mesh.edges and not reference_mesh.polygons:
...     print("do something")
...     
>>>
```

Keep in mind, while in Python it's idiomatic to write `if collection` to check if it contains something or `if not collection` to check if it's empty, sometimes it fails, for example in the past there was a problem with numpy arrays filled with zeroes to convert to `False` boolean value (today you get a warning or an error). Similarly, the idiomatic way to compare two objects is `is`, but in Blender many objects are just short-lived wrappers, so be careful writing slick Python code:

```py
>>> arm = D.armatures['Armature']
>>> arm.bones[0] is arm.bones[0]
False
```

Comment: Thank you Markus. I've made some tests. See my answer below. I guess, I've a diffrent problem in my code. I'll have to dig deeper into it...

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following routine, to check my problem. All works fine here. So I guess, I've another problem with my actual code. I'm an (advanced) beginner in Blender Python. Maybe I need to check my code for other issues.

The difference to my own code is, I transfer the selected mesh in to a new var, called "reference_mesh" and when trying to check for "reference_mesh.polygons" it seem to create problems.

```
import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_ScaleBasedOnPolygons(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.scale_based_on_polygons"
    bl_label = "Scale"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type == 'MESH':
                if obj.data.polygons:
                    obj.scale *= 0.5  # Scale objects with polygons by 0.5
                else:
                    obj.scale *= 2.0  # Scale objects without polygons by 2
        
        return {'FINISHED'}

# ============== GUI ==============

class CWToolsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "CW Test"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    bl_category = 'Tool'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.operator("object.scale_based_on_polygons")

# ============== Register ==============

classes = (
    CWToolsPanel,
    OBJECT_OT_ScaleBasedOnPolygons,
)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Assuming the code here has a problem (which it doesn't if I read you correctly), this is the simplest debugging approach: put a `print("name", obj.name)` and `print("polygons", obj.data.polygons[:])` inside the `if obj.data.polygons:` - now you can see which objects report to have polygons, find the one that shouldn't, check if it indeed lists the polygons. You can further add prints to investigate the object, e.g. `obj.data.name` to see which mesh it uses and so on.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady do you know if deleting the faces of an would remove the attribute `obj.data.polygons` or would its still exist and the check should be `len(obj.data.polygons)'

Comment: @Ratt the `polygons` will always exist, but sometimes be empty (and `bool(empty_collection) == False`). I suspect in this case it's just a bug elsewhere.